# Help understanding "again" at the end of "a long time before he saw his family again"

Tags: meaning-in-context, time

> It would be a long time before he saw his family again.

I understand nothing of this sentence. The times it expresses. Specially "again" at the end confuse me.

Answer (score 1):

If you were talking about something that is happening now, you would be talking about something that will happen in the future, so you would say:

> It **will** be a long time before he **sees** his family again

The [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/again) defines again as **one more time**: in this sentence, it is referring to the next time he will see his family.

Because the writer is talking about a situation in the past, **will** and **see** are moved into the past:

> It **would** be a long time before he **saw** his family again

Comment: Thanks, but need a little more, is it "It would be a long time - before he saw his family again" or "It would be a long time before - he saw his family again".

Comment: **before** is a conjunction. It links together two clauses "It would be a long time" and "he saw his family again". I don't understand why you think that it would change anything to add a dash before or after the conjunction.

Comment: Because I thought "a long time before" is one phrase or 'before

Comment: It was my wrong way of thinking.bcos I thought "a long time before" is a seperate phrase or " before ..... again" is a seperate sentence in the same. But I got your point now. Thank you for your time.